# Jquery sorting multiple items and 2 digit numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have little problem in sorting.

Now i have 3 categories where i have to sort name, price and quantity.

with this script its work when i sory by name and price but it totaly mess up the quantity.

where is the problem and is there better solution to fix this?
Also 2 digit numbers are not good, when its 10 its put it behind 1.

JS:

```
function sortUsingNestedText(parent, childSelector, keySelector, sortType) {
    var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b) {
        var vA = $(keySelector, a).text();
        var vB = $(keySelector, b).text();


        if(sortType=='price') {
            vA = parseInt(vA.substr(1));
            vB = parseInt(vB.substr(1));
        }               
        return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
    parent.append(items);
}

/* setup sort attributes */
$('#sName').data("sortKey", "span.name");
$('#sPrice').data("sortKey", "span.price");
$('#sQuantity').data("sortKey", "span.items");


/* sort on button click */
$(".btnSort").click(function() {
   sortUsingNestedText($('#list-category-results'), "li", $(this).data("sortKey"), $(this).data('sortType'));
});
```

HTML:

```
    <ul id="sort-options" class="clearfix">
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="sName" class="btnSort">
                Name
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="sPrice" class="btnSort">
                Price
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li>
            <a href="#" id="sQuantity" class="btnSort">
                quantity
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Items to sort -->

    <ul id="list-category-results" class="clearfix">
        <li>

                <span class="name">ferrari</span>
                <span class="price">35</span>
                <span class="quantity">200</span>

        </li>
        <li>

                <span class="name">aston martin</span>       
                <span class="price">6</span>
                 <span class="items">600</span>

        </li>

        <li>

                <span class="name">audi</span>                    
                <span class="price">10</span>
                 <span class="items">400</span>

        </li>
        <li>

                <span class="name">bmw</span>                
                <span class="price">20</span>
                 <span class="items">1099</span>

        </li>
        <li>

                <span class="name">lambhorgini</span>                
                <span class="price">25</span>
                 <span class="items">185</span>

        </li>



    </ul>
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/w7ygmm63/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you were comparing the text of the quantity vs the actual number. you needed to do something similar to what you were doing for price but also there was no need to sub str the text to the first character in the `parseInt`

http://jsfiddle.net/w7ygmm63/1/

```
function sortUsingNestedText(parent, childSelector, keySelector, sortType) {
    var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b) {
        var vA = $(keySelector, a).text();
        var vB = $(keySelector, b).text();


        if(sortType==='numeric') {
            vA = parseInt(vA, 10);
            vB = parseInt(vB, 10);
        }               
        return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
    parent.append(items);
}

/* setup sort attributes */
$('#sName').data("sortKey", "span.name");
$('#sPrice').data("sortKey", "span.price");
$('#sPrice').data("sortType", "numeric");
$('#sQuantity').data("sortKey", "span.quantity");
$('#sQuantity').data("sortType", "numeric");


/* sort on button click */
$(".btnSort").click(function() {
   sortUsingNestedText($('#list-category-results'), "li", $(this).data("sortKey"), $(this).data('sortType'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Still learning this stuff, so with some parts im not quite familiar.

Comment: thinking about it a bit further since quantity and price use the same operation to enable sorting they should have the same sort type ill update.